# There are 10 stations on a circular path

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are 10 stations on a circular path. A train has to stop at 4 stations such that no two stations are adjacent. How many such selections are there??

Since i know if the stations are on the linear path then there would be 35 number of ways of selection, but what would be if it is on the circular path??

Answer (score 4):

The idea you used to get the $35=\binom{7}{4}$ can be adapted to the circular case.

Cut the railway line just before a station, and straighten it out. Now we have $10$ stops in a line. Either (i) we use neither of the two endstations, $\binom{5}{4}$ ways; or else (ii)  we use one endstation and therefore not the other.

If we select say the left endstation, then the next is forbidden, as is the other end. So we need to choose $3$ stops from $7$. This can be done in $\binom{5}{3}$ ways.

That gives a total of $\binom{5}{4}+2\binom{5}{3}$. The argument generalizes.