# "A combinations problem." There are $10$ halting stations on a circular road in a city....

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are $10$ halting stations on a circular road in a city. On the route, a bus will stop at any three stations so that no two stations are adjacent. The number of such possible bus routes are

I made $7$ places left to be filled in a circle which were not adjacent that gave $35$ ways of filling those up. But, the answer is $50$.
I can't get myself to the correct answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067359/there-are-10-stations-on-a-circular-path?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Allow a 1 to represent a stop and a 0 to represent a pass. If the ten are on a line you get a code like 1001000100.  We can get all codes that don't end in 1 by taking the strings 10 10 10 0 0 0 0 and putting them together.  This is like taking seven spaces and choosing 3 to be 10.  Thus there are $C(7,3)=35$ such strings.  However, we left out the ones that end in 1.  Then we have to rearrange 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 and end in an automatic 1.  There are $C(7,2)=21$ such strings. So there are a total of 35+21=56 strings.

Now put this on a circle.  The only ones which would have two 1's in a row are the ones that both begin and end in a 1.  These as strings start with 10, end with 01 and have a 1 in any of the 6 remaining spots.  Thus there are 6.  We get 56-6=50 for our answer.

Answer (score 0):

To each stop ($S$), attach a non-stop ($N$) clockwise, e.g.$\quad\boxed{SN}$

So we have $3$ boxes and $4$ others, total $7$ entities.

The boxes can  now be placed in $\binom73$ ways,
but since you are allowing each entity only $7$ positions instead of $10$,
  multiply by $\frac{10}{7}$ to get ans $= \frac{10}{7}\times\binom{7}{3} = 50$